# T-SQL to split column results and do maths on the result

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've got a table with filesizes in like so

```
FileSize
68 bytes
122.80 Kb
23.5 Mb
1.2 Gb
```

I need to SELECT the results in Mb, so the results look like

```
Converted FileSize
0.000068
0.1228
23.5
1200
```

This splits the results down correctly

```
WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([File Size],N' ',N' '),N'&',N'&amp;'),N'<',N'&lt;'),N'>',N'&gt;'),N' ',N'</x><x>') + N'</x>' AS XML) testXML
    FROM Attachment
)
SELECT testXML.value('/x[1]','float') AS Number
      ,testXML.value('/x[2]','nvarchar(max)') AS metric
FROM Splitted
```

to

```
Size      Metric
68        bytes
122.8     Kb
23.5      Mb      
1.2       Gb
```

Is there way to do the conversion on the "Size" column value based on the "Metric" column value within SQL?

Comment: What type of size would you want to convert? Is there any logic?

Comment: Just converting into Mb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be to use `CHARINDEX` to get the position of the space and split the value into the 2 columns. Then you use a `CASE` expression to multiple the value by the appropriate amount:

```sql
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT V.FileSize
    FROM (VALUES('68 bytes'),
                ('122.80 Kb'),
                ('23.5 Mb'),
                ('1.2 Gb'))V(FileSize))
SELECT *,
       V.[Size] * CASE V.Metric WHEN 'bytes' THEN 1. / (1024 * 1024)
                                WHEN 'Kb' THEN 1. / 1024
                                WHEN 'Mb' THEN 1
                                WHEN 'Gb' THEN 1024
                  END AS Megabytes
FROM YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(TRY_CONVERT(decimal(10,4),LEFT(YT.FileSize,NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ',YT.FileSize),0)-1)),STUFF(YT.FileSize,1,NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ',YT.FileSize),0),'')))V(Size,Metric)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above which I've marked as the answer, this is what I've used.

```
SELECT [File Type], [File Size],
      CAST( A.Size * CASE A.Metric WHEN 'bytes' THEN 1.0 / (1024 * 1024)
                                WHEN 'Kb' THEN 1.0 / 1024
                                WHEN 'Mb' THEN 1
                                WHEN 'Gb' THEN 1024
                  END as NUMERIC(10, 2))AS Megabytes
FROM Attachment AA
     CROSS APPLY(
        VALUES( TRY_CONVERT(decimal(10,4),LEFT(AA.[File Size], NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ',AA.[File Size]),0)-1)),
            STUFF(AA.[File Size],1,NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ',AA.[File Size]),0),''))
        )A (Size, Metric)

WHERE AA.[File Type] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Megabytes ASC
```

```
File type   File size   Megabytes
txt         68 bytes    0.00
txt         68 bytes    0.00
PDF         122.80 KB   0.12
PDF         122.80 KB   0.12
txt         23.5 Mb     23.50
PDF         1.2 Gb      1228.80
```